# is there something like SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0 in Sybase?

Tags: sql, sybase

I have the following doubt 
is there something like `SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0` in Sybase ?

I want to run this query:

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0
DELETE FROM table WHERE  fieldT = 201 AND fieldN = 3992;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That is something that you do not want to do. You would create a data integrity mess. Never even consider trying to delete from a table that has FKS without deleting from the child tables first or stopping the delte if FK records exist. For instance you would not want to delte a customer who has records in the orders table becasue you certainly would not want to delte all the information about that order (espcially financial information) in the past.

Answer (score 1):

Bad luck for you. There is nothing like that.But even if you would be able to do when you will enable that it will throw error as you are deleting the data from referenced table and thus creation of the FK wont be allowed. Best way is that.Delete from the referencing tables and then delete from referenced table. This is not only best method but great for your data integrity which is very important.